# How do extract a range from a cell (where the cell contains the range value)

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I am basically using a script that somebody else designed which draws arrows on the excel sheet between various points. I have data in my spreadsheet which shows the cells that need linking and I am trying to call the value of this cells into the call for the macro script that I am using and running it as a loop so that it creates all the arrows I want

It fails every time on the lines where I am adding .value. I have tried different ways following similar issues but none doing exactly what i am asking so i am no at a loss

the stored range value that i am trying to extract looks like this $B$5 .

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, rngstart As Range, rngend As Range

Set rng = Range("E5:E100")
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = "Yes" Then
            cell.Select
            Set rngstart = Range("K" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value
            Set rngend = Range("H" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value
            Call DrawArrows(Range(rngstart), Range(rngend), RGB(0, 0, 255), "Single")
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

the original code before  for calling the script looked like this

```
Call DrawArrows(Range("b1"), Range("c4"), RGB(0, 0, 255), "Double")
```

Comment: What is happening/the error?

Comment: `Call DrawArrows(rngstart, rngend, RGB(0, 0, 255), "Single")` maybe?

Comment: BTW, you should avoid using `.Select` if possible (I see no reason to use it in your code)

Comment: Use `cell.offset(0,x).value` instead of select.

Comment: I may have been delusional when I added select but until I did add it active row didn't seem to be picking up the right value. Having said that, I may have been delusional when I added select ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `rngstart` and `rngend` as if they were strings in your call to `DrawArrows`...

> ```
>         Call DrawArrows(Range(rngstart), Range(rngend), RGB(0, 0, 255), "Single")
> ```

...but you're treating them as objects here:

> ```
>         Set rngstart = Range("K" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value
>         Set rngend = Range("H" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value
> ```

This should be a run-time error 424, because you're retrieving a `Variant` (which based on your question is a `String` sub-type) and attempting to assign it to a variable declared as a `Range`.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    With Sheet1 '<-- you should be explicitly referencing a worksheet. replace as required.
        Set rng = .Range("E5:E100")
        For Each cell In rng
            If cell.Value = "Yes" Then
                Dim rngstart As String, rngend As String
                rngstart = .Cells(cell.Row, 11).Text
                rngend = .Cells(cell.Row, 8).Text
                'ditto with the explicit reference.
                Call DrawArrows(.Range(rngstart), .Range(rngend), RGB(0, 0, 255), "Single")
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. That works perfectly and the explanation was also extremely helpful. It will give me some food for thought next time I am editing anything in a similar fashion to ensure I get it right. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The line `Set rngstart = Range("K" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value` is assigning the `.Value` stored in column `K`, row `ActiveCell.Row` to the `Range` variable `rngstart`. You want to assign the `range` to pass in.

Doing some quick "air-coding", something like this should work:

```
Set rngstart = ActiveSheet.Range("K" & (ActiveCell.Row))
```

Note: I've specified `ActiveSheet`, because that's what the otherwise unquilified `Range` points to - at least this way it's explicit. Also, this could easily break if someone were to click on another sheet, or the button is on a different sheet than the one where you're looking to pick up the cell address from.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to my problem.

Comment: @KarlGriffiths - you're welcome. the normal way of saying "thanks" is to click the "up arrow" button next to the answer. That lets others know that the answer is useful, even though it may not have been the "best" answer or your final solution.

Comment: I can only select one. If I set yours it removes it from the other one

Comment: @KarlGriffiths, not the check mark (which is fine where it is, Comintern provided a much more complete answer), but the up arrow above the number.

Comment: Gotcha. I have done that. But I have such a low rep currently (not used the site much) that apparently it doesn't change the score